# Best way to return json in html response

Tags: jquery, html, json

In my html response I need to return some json and pass to a javascript function that is called on the page. My current approach is to use jQuery, something like the following:

```
...
<div id="json" style="display: none">{"attr1": "Some attr"}</div>
<script>$(function() { myfunc($('#json').text()) })</script>
...
```

This works fine but I am wondering is this the recommended way to approach the problem?

Comment: It looks like you could simply do `<script>myfunc(YOUR_JSON_GOES_HERE)</script>` (the approach used by jsonp technique to overcome cross-origin issue) If you do need both html and json simultaneosly for some reason.

Comment: Important: depending on how you include the data, you may need to properly encode the data (e.g. with `htmlspecialchars` in PHP) to ensure that special characters (which vary based on context: `<`, `"`, `'`...) do not alter the meaning of your JSON.